# Integral of the exponential function

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am searching the indefinite integral of this function:  $\dfrac{\exp(x)}{(1+x)^{5/3}}$.
Thank you alot.

Comment: First thing I would do is make a change if variable from $x+1=u$

Comment: It cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. See [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) and/or [incomplete $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) for more details.

Comment: I have tried integration by parts, twice after that I find the integral of exp(x^3) dx. any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for the holy grail since, as Lucian just said, functions like $e^{x^n}$ (with $n\geq 2$) do not have an "elementary" antiderivative.

Comment: Are you looking for a primitive or for the value of a specific integral of this function?

Comment: I am looking for the autocorrelation function of the power spectral density of wind. It is done hereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral is not elementary:

First rewrite your integral:
$$\int{\frac{e^x}{(x+1)^{5/3}}}{dx} = e^{-1}\int{\frac{e^{x+1}}{(x+1)^{5/3}}}{dx}$$
Make a substitution $u = x+1$ and $du = dx$
$$e^{-1}\int{\frac{e^{x+1}}{(x+1)^{5/3}}}{dx} = e^{-1}\int{\frac{e^{u}}{u^{5/3}}}{du}$$
Make another substitution: $s = u^{1/3}$ and $du = 3s^2ds$
$$e^{-1}\int{\frac{e^{u}}{u^{5/3}}}{du} = 3e^{-1}\int{\frac{e^{s^3}}{s^3}}{ds}$$
The last integral is not elementary (which can be proven by the Risch Algorithm).
Thus you can conclude that your initial integral is not an elementary function.

However, your integral has a closed form in terms of special functions (using Mathematica): 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{s(\omega)e^{\tau*I*\omega}}{d\omega} = \frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2/3} \pi  \text{c1} |r|^{2/3} \left(-i
   \text{sgn}(r) \left(3 \left(\sqrt[3]{-\text{c2}}-\sqrt[3]{\text{c2}}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{2 |r|}{3 \text{c2}}\right)-\sqrt{3}
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-\text{c2}}+\sqrt[3]{\text{c2}}\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 |r|}{3
   \text{c2}}\right)\right)+3 \left(\sqrt[3]{\text{c2}}-\sqrt[3]{-\text{c2}}\right)
   \sin \left(\frac{2 |r|}{3 \text{c2}}\right)-\sqrt{3}
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-\text{c2}}+\sqrt[3]{\text{c2}}\right) \cos \left(\frac{2 |r|}{3
   \text{c2}}\right)\right)}{3 \text{c2}^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$

with the restrictions: $r \in \mathbb{R} \land c2 \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R} \lor c2 = 0$

Comment: Can I find the definite value of this integral numerically?

Comment: Of course. But you need to specify the constants first.
What do you mean with $-\infty < \tau <\infty$? Is this a double integral?